# How do I access files and directories in a zip file using bash script?

Tags: command-line, bash, directory, cd, zip

I want to be able to navigate to files located in a zip file from the terminal. I can access the files and directories on the graphical user interface, but I can't seem to use `cd` to get to them like I can with other folders.

I've tried:
`cd path/to/.zipfile/and/the/things/inside`
and even
`vi path/to/.zipfile/and/a/file/inside`
but both times I get the error:
`no such file or directory` even though I know for sure that they exist.

I'm not sure how unzipping works- if the unzip releases all the things inside or if you can unzip and pull certain things out and then zip it all back up again pretty easily. I would prefer not to unleash everything inside the zip file, if possible.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `unzip` command with its `-l` option.
`man unzip` says about the `-l` option:

> list  archive files (short format).  The names, uncompressed file
>   sizes and modification dates and times of the specified  files  are 
>   printed along  with totals for all files specified.

For example you are in `~/sed` directory,in which there is a zip file named *my.zip*, you should do:

```
me@me-K52JT:~/sed$ unzip -l my.zip
```

The output will be:

```
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
      752  2019-07-10 20:24   a.txt
      101  2019-07-10 18:33   b.txt
---------                     -------
      853                     2 files
```

So you can see the list of files in your zip without extracting it. The default behavior of `unzip` (with no options) is to extract into the current directory.

Comment: What does the -l option do and what arguments do I need to give it?

Comment: If I want to extract a folder located within the zip file, do I do `unzip -l .zipfile/path/to/folder`?